# Ignoring case sensitivity

Tags: c#

I have to count how many times each word from given input text appears in it.
And the thing where I'm stuck: The character casing differences should be ignored.

For example: "You are here.You you" -> the output :

```
are=1
here=1
You=3
```

What I've done:

```
string text = "You are here.You you";
IDictionary<string, int> wordsCount = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
string[] words = text.Split(' ',',','.','-','!');

foreach (string word in words)
{
    int count = 1;
    if (wordsCount.ContainsKey(word))
        count = wordsCount[word] + 1;
    wordsCount[word] = count;
}
var items = from pair in wordsCount
            orderby pair.Value ascending
            select pair;
foreach (var p in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", p.Key, p.Value);
}
```

There is a chance to make this possible without checking manually every word from the given text? For example if I have a very long paragraph to not check every word using the specific method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
for(i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++){
    text[i] = text[i].ToLower();
}
```

But as `text` is a string, just do :

```
text = text.ToLower();
```

Just before the `string[] words = text.Split(' ',',','.','-','!');` line.
And then enjoy !

Comment: Sorry, what should I put in front of toLower to work?

Comment: You wrote: text[i] = tolower(text[i]). What's this "tolower"?

Comment: toLower must be applied to a string. `text[i] = text[i].toLower()`

Comment: Sorry I confounded with C, I apologize !

Answer (score 0):

How about linq?

```
var text = "You are here.You you";
var words = text.Split(' ', ',', '.', '-', '!');

words
    .GroupBy(word => word.ToLowerInvariant())
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(g=> Console.WriteLine(g.Key + "=" + g.Count()));
```